# SQL query to identify supervisor with employee number and job title

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and working on a list to generate employee list with their reporting VPs. the challenge that I have is that not all employees directly reports to VPs, some requires to go through multiple reporting channel to reach VPs.

What I did was creating CTE for each reporting channel and try to join but this method still does not work. For instance, if an employee A reports to supervisor, then supervisor reports to manager, then the manager reports to senior manager, then the senior manager reports to director, and the director reports to VP of their business unit, I need a table lists the information of employee A and the VP responsible for that business unit in following format
Employee number, firstname, lastname, username, jobtitle, VPusername
Below is the script I came up. Would someone please review and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

```
With Employee
as 
(
SELECT [EmployeeNumber]
      ,[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
  FROM [BASE_DB].[dbo].[HR_list_180604] 
  ),
  Tier1sup
  as
  (
  SELECT sup1.[EmployeeNumber]
      --,emp.[EmployeeNumber]
      ,sup1.[Username]
      ,sup1.[JobTitle]
      ,sup1.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber] 
  FROM [BASE_DB].[dbo].[HR_list_180604] sup1
        left join Employee as emp on emp.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber] = sup1.[EmployeeNumber]
  where sup1.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%'
  ),
    Tier2sup
  as
  (
  SELECT sup2.[EmployeeNumber]
      --,emp.[EmployeeNumber]
      ,sup2.[Username]
      ,sup2.[JobTitle]
      ,sup2.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
  FROM [BASE_DB].[dbo].[HR_list_180604] sup2
        left join Tier1sup as tier1 on Tier1.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber] = sup2.[EmployeeNumber]
        --left join Employee as emp on emp.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber] = Tier1sup.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
  where sup2.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%'
  ),
  Tier3sup
  as
  (
  SELECT sup3.[EmployeeNumber]
      --,emp.[EmployeeNumber]
      ,sup3.[Username]
      ,sup3.[JobTitle]
      ,sup3.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
  FROM [BASE_DB].[dbo].[HR_list_180604] sup3
        left join Tier2sup as tier2 on Tier2.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber] = sup3.[EmployeeNumber]
  where sup3.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%'
  )

  select T1.[EmployeeNumber]
      ,T1.[FirstName]
      ,T1.[LastName]
      ,T1.[Username]
      ,T1.[JobTitle]
      ,case 
        when sup1.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%' then sup1.[Username]
        when sup2.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%' then sup2.[Username]
        when sup3.[JobTitle] like '%VP,%' then sup2.[Username]
      end as SupUser

      from [BASE_DB].[dbo].[HR_list_180604] T1 
        left join Employee as emp on T1.[EmployeeNumber] = emp.[EmployeeNumber]
        left join Tier1sup as sup1 on sup1.[EmployeeNumber] = emp.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
        left join Tier2sup as sup2 on sup2.[EmployeeNumber] = sup1.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
        left join Tier3sup as sup3 on sup3.[EmployeeNumber] = sup2.[SupervisorEmployeeNumber]
```

Comment: This really belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com